# Detecting offsetTop changes

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have a page which can't have scroll bars, so everything has to appear in the view all the time. On the image below you can see the basic setup of the screen, so you can get the representation of it.

[image: sample]

So, there are two blocks (1 and 2). The first one (1) is expandable, or it can even doesn't exist based on the content. The max-height is 500px for that block and I don't support mobile devices, only iPads and computers will be supported. The second block (2) exists all the time, no matter what.

The questions is:
How to dynamically resize the second block, based on the `offsetTop`?

Mainly I've tried to work with that through `@ViewChild()`, but it doesn't detect changes all the time and that makes the page to go beyond the view area.

This is how I've tried to work with that.

```
@ViewChild('block2') set offset(content: ElementRef) {
    content.nativeElement.style.maxHeight = `calc(100vh - ${this.offsetTop + 20}px)`;
}
```

Unfortunately, I can't share the source code, but any ideas will be highly appreciated.

The second block has to listen to the offsetTop changes all the time, and to fill the bottom space of the page.

Comment: Why can't you share code? You need to at least add a minimal and complete code block so we can see what we are working with. We have no idea of your HTML structure or CSS. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What happens if all the content won't fit on the screen?  Anyway, you are probably wanting to bind something to window.resize as if you aren't having any scrolling, that's the only time that the offset will change.  But as you aren't able to share your code, this question is off topic for SO and therefore I'm voting to close

Comment: @Pete Well, even if it lack some code, at least the explanation is clear and understandable. As he seem to be a new user (like I am), it is better to explain him clearly, like disinfor did, before instantly claiming the topic is non valuable and closing it. He did wrong but (unlike some other questions I came accross) he did put some effort in it.

Comment: @KawaLo Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**.  SO is a repository of information for future users that may have the same problem.  If there is no code in the question then we are unable to debug the code and any answer we give will be an absolute guess.  If you don't like the rules of SO then perhaps bring it up on meta - don't have a go at me for enforcing them.  You may need to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @Pete Part of the code used in the project is commercial and can't be shared. That's why I have drawn an illustration of how it looks.

The content inside these two blocks is scrollable, so that's not the problem. The only requirement was these blocks must to be in the view all the time, but their contents can be scrollable. Data shown inside are tables.

Comment: @D3N1EL please read the link in my above comment - as you have no code, the question is also too broad - there are too many ways to do this.  It also becomes a please do my code for me in which case you want to hire someone - this is not a forum for that - this is for where you have a specific problem with in your code and don't know how to debug it.  Please also refresh yourself with [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Also the reason why you need actual code in question is that some people  are unable to access sites like imigur due to firewalls

Comment: Anyway as this question is off topic and you are not willing / able to fix it, I am moving on.  Good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle this with just css, no need to use javascript (it makes complex and non optimized calculations that can be easily handled by your browser). Instead, use a flex box.

*index.html*

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="expandable">
    I am expandable
  </div>
  <div>
    I am not
  </div>
</div>
```

*index.css*

```css
#container {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /* Ensure your container takes the full screen */
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;

  /* Here is the magic */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

#container > *:not([class="expandable"]) {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Now, you can programmatically set the height of your expandable div, and the second one will automatically resize, without flowing outside the screen.

**EDIT**

May not work perfectly like this, you may need to adjust one thing or two, depending on how your original project works. `flex-grow`, when applied to a flex child (not the flex container), will make the child expand automatically, to fill the remaining space.

More details here : [MDN - Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow)

Comment: It was simpler that I thought! Thank you a lot.

There were minor adjustments to the child components of the second block, but you couldn't know about it, so your css worked 100% without modifications.